# How do I escape a space in Jade(pug) template just in template file?

Tags: javascript, pug

I did some search but couldn't find any people discussing this.

Here is my issue.

I have a variable passed in Jade Compiler and it contains space in it.

For example:

```
<a href="#{option.content}">test link</a>
```

What if there are spaces in the `option.content` part. Do I have to escape it before it's passed in the HTML page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really JavaScript and not pug, but you still see this a lot in pug when you're parsing JSON inputs.

The first variable name can't have spaces in it by JavaScript object standards, but properties of a JavaScript object can definitely have spaces in them.  Let's take this (really poorly designed) object as an example:

```
var myObject = {
  "object type": "person",
  "person name": {
    "first name": "Lebron",
    "last name": "James",
    "initials": "LJ"
  }
};
```

You can access individual fields using square brackets and the property name in quotes, and fields that don't have spaces can still use periods:

```
myObject['object type']                 // returns "person"
myObject['person name']['first name']   // returns "Lebron"

myObject['person name'].initials        // returns "LJ"
myObject['person name']['initials']     // returns "LJ"
```